# XHR Page keeps on reloading after Cookie check

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

This is my js-code, I thing I have a loop in the xhr request as it keeps loading even without the cookies function;
I am trying to show the "TnC" if no cookie is there. However it keeps on replading the request if it is a no.

Also when I click on agree on the submit form it reloads.

Thank you a lot for the help

//cookies function:

```
   function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
   if(document.getElementById('agree').checked){
    const d = new Date();
   d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
   let expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
   document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
   }   
   }

   function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
   }
    return "";
 }
```

//cokkie on load + XHR

```
  function checkCookieOnLoad() {
  if(getCookie("clicklink") === "yes") {
 


   var elem = document.getElementById("tmx");
                elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);




            var video = document.createElement('video');
            video.type = "video/mp4";
            video.src = ".//vid1.mp4";
            video.autoplay = true;
            video.muted = true;
            video.id = "vdd1"
            document.body.appendChild(video);

            
            video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
            // current time is given in seconds

                            if(this.currentTime >= 4.8) {
                                // pause the playback
                                this.pause();
                                this.remove();
                                
                                
        location.replace("https://test.com");
                                }

            });

   return true;

  
 
   } else {
 
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          const contianer = document.getElementById('tmx');
          xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status ===200){
              contianer.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
          }
          xhr.open('get', 'tnc.html');
          xhr.send();
 
 
    }
 }
```